# Making cytoscape.js animations play continuously

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there any way to make an animation play continuously?

Here is a [demo](https://jsbin.com/pinobigelo/edit?html,output) using `ani.play()` but it does it only **once**. Not continuously.

I want a '*flashing*' node. It should grow and shrink in size constantly till the user says stop.

For now, I've done this

```
var jAni = cy.$('#rose').animation({
  style: {
    'background-color': 'red',
    'width': 75
  },
  duration: 1000
});
jAni.play();
```

Exactly as mentioned in the documentation for `ani.play()`

Comment: would you care giving an example, @TheHeadRush

Comment: It would be better for you to edit some code that failed to produce the desired outcome into your post.

Comment: @TheHeadRush any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Never used `cytoscape.js`, but you only call `play()` once. i'd experiment with wrapping the `play()` call in a `do...while` block, perhaps with the use of a `setTimeout` if the animation restarts before completion. Or else figure out how to make the itself animation loop.

Comment: @TheHeadRush this is their documentation - http://js.cytoscape.org/#ani.play . Shouldn't it loop automatically as per it?

Comment: No, it says that calling `play` starts that animation from the next frame if it was stopped while playing or from the beginning otherwise.

Comment: It says - If the animation is complete, start from the beginning. That should mean it loops

Comment: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/src/animation.js . If you check the source code for `play()` it mentions _auto-rewind_ . So I'm assuming its a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must chain your promises.  Auto-rewind doesn't mean auto-replay, just like a tape.

```
let loopAnimation = ele => {
  return (
    ele.animation(opts).play()
    .promise('complete').then(loopAnimation)
  );
};

loopAnimation(someNode);
```

Comment: It is not doing anything. I'm on reactjs inside a `useEffect` function

`let loopAnimation = () => {
      return (
        cy.edges().animation({ style: { "line-dash-offset": 48, }, duration: 1000, }).play()
          .promise('complete').then(loopAnimation)
      );
    };
    loopAnimation();`